# How to add a click and a long click listener on the same view using databinding?

Tags: android, data-binding, onclicklistener, android-databinding, onlongclicklistener

I have this layout file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data class="ItemDataBinding">
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.example.data.Item" />

        <variable
            name="onItemClickListener"
            type="com.example.OnItemClickListener" />

        <variable
            name="onLongShoppingListClickListener"
            type="com.example.OnLongItemClickListener" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{(v) -> onItemClickListener.onItemClick(item)}">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_text_view"
            android:text="@{item.getName()}"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

With a single click listener, it works fine. I tried:

```
android:onClick="@{(v) -> onItemClickListener.onItemClick(item), onLongItemClickListener.onLongItemClick(item)}">
```

But it doesn't work. How to add both listeners on the same view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create own `ClickHander` and use it in `XML` like below.

```
    <data>

         <variable
                name="item"
                type="com.example.data.Item" />

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="embitel.com.databindingexample.helper.ClickHander" />

    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onLongClick="@{(v) -> handler.onLongClickOnHeading(v, item)}"
        android:onClick="@{(v)->handler.onItemClicked(v,item)}">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_text_view"
            android:text="@{item.getName()}"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Your `ClickHandler` class

```
    public class ClickHander {

    public void onItemClicked(View v, Item item) {
        Context context = v.getContext();
        // Your code 
    }

    // For long click
    public void onLongClickOnHeading(View v, Item item) {
        Context context = v.getContext();
        // Your code 
    }
}
```

set Binding from your `Activity` or `Fragment`

```
binding.setHandler(new ClickHander());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still don't understand how to handle both events, click and long click. You just changed the way of handling the event. I looking for handling both events on the same view.

Comment: Let me try and get back to you. Voted-up.

Comment: Is it really necessary to add the `View v` as argument in the `onItemClicked()`?

Comment: Yes its required.